# Edit csv filename based on contents

Tags: csv, batch-file, cmd

I have a load of csv files with my work hours in. A given file might look like this:

```
Day,"Clocked In","Pay From","Clocked Out","Pay To",Type,Confirmed,Lunchtime,HH:MM
Monday,"12-Dec-2016 08:17","12-Dec-2016 08:17","12-Dec-2016 17:27","12-Dec-2016 17:27",,ABC,00:30,08:40
Tuesday,"13-Dec-2016 08:32","13-Dec-2016 08:32","13-Dec-2016 17:26","13-Dec-2016 17:26",,EEF,00:30,08:24
Wednesday,"14-Dec-2016 08:16","14-Dec-2016 08:16","14-Dec-2016 13:08","14-Dec-2016 13:08",,ABC,,04:52
Wednesday,"14-Dec-2016 13:08","14-Dec-2016 13:08","14-Dec-2016 17:30","14-Dec-2016 17:30",,AIF,00:30,03:52
Thursday,"15-Dec-2016 08:28","15-Dec-2016 08:28",,,,,00:00,00:00
```

I am trying to create a program (maybe a batch file combined with task scheduler) that runs at a certain time each day/ whenever a new csv file is exported to my documents. It renames all csv files found there based on column 2 row 2 ie. the date of the first entry that week. It moves the files to a specified location `(C:\Users\ [username]\Documents\Data)` where any files with the same value in R2C2 are deleted leaving only the one that was exported most recently.

### A few details:

The files are currently named like `[username]_export_15_Dec_2016 09_03_50.csv` with the date and time of creation in the filename. I want to end up with `12-Dec-2016.csv` the R2C2 value of the .csv file minus the time. So I imagine this original filename can be used to delete any older file with the same R2C2 value, meaning I no longer have any duplicates.

I've tried the following code simply to rename the files, but quickly realised I did not know how to implement the code (get it to run whenever I export a new csv file to my documents), nor how to do any of the automatic deleting. I am however using power query in excel for analysis, and if the filenames contained enough info I could probably do the duplicate removal through that.

```
@echo off
for %%i in (*.csv) do call :REN "%%i"
del *.csv
ren *.new *.csv
Pause
goto :EOF

:REN
for /F "skip=1 tokens=2 delims=," %%j in ('type "%~1"') do (
  copy "%~1" "%~n1-"Clocked In"%%j.new" > nul & goto :EOF)
```

Also the current code (when run through a .bat file in My documents) deletes all the .csv files or at least removes them so that I can't find them anywhere, and I'm not sure why (you can probably tell I'm utterly unfamiliar with this kind of programming)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can't see the "following code" you mention...

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
del "flagfile" >nul 2>nul
:again
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%f IN ('dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*.csv"') DO (
 SET "renamed="
 FOR /f "usebackqskip=1tokens=2delims=, " %%a IN ("%sourcedir%\%%f") DO (
  IF NOT DEFINED renamed IF "%%~nf" neq "%%~a" ECHO( MOVE /y "%sourcedir%\%%f" "%sourcedir%\%%~a.csv" 
  SET renamed=Y
 )
)
timeout /t 20 >nul
if not exist "flagfile" goto again
GOTO :EOF
```

You would need to change the setting of `sourcedir` to suit your circumstances.

The required MOVE commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO(MOVE` to `MOVE` to actually move the files.  Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file moved`)

Scans the source directory for `.csv` files, assigning each name to `%%f` in turn.

sets the `renamed` flag and reads the file, skipping the first line and assigning the new name to `%%a` from the second "column" where a column is delimited by `,` and .

If the `renamed` flag has not yet been set, then we are on line2, so check whether the current name in `%%f` (name part only) is the same as that in `%%a` (after removing the quote). If the name is different, then execute the `move` to rename the file, overwriting any existing file with the name in `%%~a`.

Then set the `renamed` flag regardless so that succeeding lines of the `.csv` don't attempt to rename the file again

---

I've added a simple scheduler into the routine. It relies on a file that can be placed anywhere you like with whatever name you like.

First, you delete the flagfile

Then, after the main routine has been run, you add a `timeout` where the number following `/t` is an integral number of seconds. The `>nul` suppresses `timeout`'s prompts.

When the timeout has elapsed, the routine checks for flagfile. If it's absent, we re-run the routine, capturing any new files. If it's present, we exit, so all you need to do to stop the batch is to create the flagfile.

Comment: Small edit: `SET "sourcedir=C:\Users\ [username]\Documents` is now followed by  `SET "enddir=C:\Users\ [username]\Documents\Data` and I altered `MOVE...` to 
`MOVE /y "%sourcedir%\%%f" "%` **`enddir`** `%\%%~a.csv"` 
to allow different source and output folders. I tested and this doesn't seem to mess with deleting older files, but I'm not familiar with the code, is this okay to do?

Comment: Also, can I set this to run when a new .csv is added to the source directory, or will I have to just schedule a task/ run the program manually?

Comment: Seems fine to me. I'll add a poor-man's scheduler into the code if you're not comfortable using the task scheduler. That way, all you need to do is execute the batch minimised in your start-up.

Comment: Thanks! Bit messy to have the batch file open all the time, but I suppose that's necessary to be constantly monitoring the flag file? Or can it be monitored with a background (invisible not just minimised) process. Like a Task Scheduler trigger.